# Console log doesn't work in candidate channel of Snapcraft (nodejs plugin)

Tags: node.js, snapcraft

Recently I am studying ubuntu core. So I made a simple snap using snap to print message in console. It is really simple, just print a message, or input-param + message.

My question is, I have no idea why the snap work in dev mode, but not working in candidate channel.

Here is my sample code.

**snapcraft.yaml**

```
name: saybye
version: "1.0.0"
summary: Command-line tool for saying byebye to someone
description: |
  saybye
  saybye name
grade: stable
confinement: strict

apps:
  saybye:
    command: saybye

parts:
  saybye:
    plugin: nodejs
    source: .
```

**saybye.js**

```
#! /usr/bin/env node

let name = null;
if (process && process.argv && Array.isArray(process.argv) && process.argv.length > 2) {
  name = process.argv[2];
}

let message = null;
let greeting = "Bye Bye!";

if (!name)
  message = greeting;
else
  message = name + ' ' + greeting;

console.log(message);
```

And it's npm config **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "saybye",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "saybye.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "bin": {
    "saybye": "saybye.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/hubertwang/saybye/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/hubertwang/saybye#readme"
}
```

As you can see, the code here is really simple. Basically they are come from some first time tutorials. It works if you install the snap in dev mode.

But if you install the candidate I uploaded to store, it won't work.

```
sudo snap install saybye --channel=candidate
```

I am not sure if the issue is caused by some interface setting, maybe I didn't ask for the permission I need to print message?

Comment: What's means "it won't work" ? Can't able to install the snap or you get nothing when launching the command  saybye ??